# jQuery append fails on first pass of for loop (but succeeds on others)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a `for` loop to iterate through data from a weather API. Within that for loop, I'm assigning each night a rating on its suitability for stargazing (`var totalRanking`). Then I update a series of `div`s, having IDs `day0`, `day1`, etc., with this rating. (If it matters, these divs are being generated dynamically.) Here's the code block in question:

```
var dayRankLine = $("<div>");
var rating = $("<span class=rating>"); // happens
rating.text(Math.round(totalRanking * 100) + "%"); // happens
dayRankLine.html("Score: "); // happens
dayRankLine.append(rating); // doesn't happen on 0. (does on others)
$("#day" + i).after(dayRankLine); // happens (even on 0)
```

As shown in the comments, the first div, `#day0`, is getting text `Score:`, but no number. The remaining divs are working as expected. A later code block uses the `rating` for day 0 to update a different DOM element, and works as expected, showing that the correct value is getting input.

What's different about the first iteration through the loop, and what's different about appending, that that line should fail on that pass only?

Comment: Do you have a (non)working example/fiddle? There's no for loop in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh nevermind. As I said, I was using `rating` in a lower code block, and that was "stealing" it from day0. `rating.clone()` and problem solved.